# Introduction to driver programming

Tags: c, debian, driver, raspberry-pi

Driver programming is one of those things that I wanted to at least have an idea about for quite some time, but whenever I had some time to spare at my hands and sat down for research, I almost exclusively found very special questions about the matter or very broad introductions.
Now I do understand that it is not a trivial topic, but I personally learn best from sitting down and doing stuff. Therefore, I hope that you can give me a few pointers where to start. So, for the sake of a hands-on approach, consider the following scenario: I have a Raspberry Pi at my hands and want to utilize the GPIO pins as a serial port. (I'd love to hear other suggestions if you believe this is to complex for a starter's project. It's really more for the sake of doing it, the result is secondary). So the Pi runs Debian wheezy, and that's where I start from.
Given this, what do I need (software-wise) to get started? Specifically I am asking for the following:

- Which compiler do I use?
- Apart from the compiler and a text editor, do I need more tools?
- Is there a some kind of scheme that I could copy to get started?
- Do you maybe know of a great introduction that I just haven't had the luck to come across? I found that recorded lectures can be extremely helpful, and I would absolutely be willing to sit through a full course if that gets me started.
- Do you know of a project simple enough for a beginner to learn from it by reading the sources on e.g. github?

And finally, am I totally on the wrong track? I might well be; I have been programming for quite some time, but usually in the high abstraction levels that languages with runtimes provide. I do have some experience regarding C++ programming and pointers aren't black magic to me, but I am not on very familiar ground here.
Also, if a blatant lack of understanding of drivers speaks out of this post, please point it out to me.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about writing a physical device driver, rather than a logical one (which is usually what I think of when I think 'driver'). Have you tried using an arduino? http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in Linux, so what you have already installed (or available to install) should be enough to build with - a modern C compiler and make system, along with a decent editor. You even get a debugger capable of debugging both user and kernel space code - gdb & kgdb. Depending on what hardware you're tinkering with you may need something to look at what it's doing.

As for an introduction to drivers, there's two aspects you're asking about here. 1) O/S specific driver models, for Linux - start here: [Linux Device Drivers](http://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf) and if that makes no sense to you, you know you need to go back a step and get some more basics down! 2) General aspects of h/w and terminology. I'm not sure of a good general resource here.

One final thing, C++ is not C, which is also not assembler which is also not machine code. At the level of battling hardware into life, you start having to know about the dirty secrets below the abstractions you normally use. There's plenty of information around about this sort of stuff but that's sort of the problem, there is a *LOT* to know. You could try Ulrich Dreppers article about memory, [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf), or you could look into what goes on with pre-emption and multi-tasking. Or you could look at [datasheets](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) for the hardware you're looking to control. There's plenty out there.

You've asked an *incredibly* general question, I'm surprised it's not been closed, however come back here when you've got stuff going and you have some specific questions to ask!

Answer (score 2):

I never wrote a full fledged driver for a specific hardware, but I've gone through some basics in driver programming.

If you're into linux, before getting into driver programming you need to know what are drivers..? types of drivers..? how are drivers inserted as modules in kernel..? [Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html) is the link. There is a basic abstract how to insert a driver or how to remove a driver from kernel and lot more.

There are [video](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=linux%20kernel%20module%20programming%20&sm=3) tutorials in youtube.

After you get enough stuff here, go through the [LDD Book](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)(Very nice book for beginners) as suggested by Joe.

Here's some more..
character driver [example](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/kbuild-linux-kernel-build-system?page=0,2).

you may also wanted to know about [kernel compilation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html), which is an intresting and important topic before starting driver programming, understand static and dyanamic(loadable) drivers.